# Python Raspberry PI PyGame Audio error - just a click

Tags: python, audio, pygame, raspberry-pi, alsa

Brand new to Python and also to using Raspberry Pi

Trying a very simple hookup to Arduino and using pyGame to play sounds when buttons are pressed.

Unfortunately i cant get the .wav files to actually play - i just get a click sound. I assumed  it was samplerate so i checked the audio file and set the pygame.mixer.pre_init to be the same sample rate and it still doesnt work.

I installed alsa-utils and mpg321 and set the pi to output audio via hdmi

I can use aplay to play the mp3 file. I can also get pyhton using os. to play the mp3

Using pyGame i cant load the mp3 as it gives an error that it cant find the file
Using pygame.sound it does run the script and recieve the button press but all i get is a click.

Ill get the pi and post the error codes exactly but heres the python

```
# playSounds.py

import pygame.mixer
from time import sleep
from sys import exit
import serial

pygame.mixer.init(44000, -16, 1, 1024) 

soundA = pygame.mixer.Sound("/1.wav") 
soundB = pygame.mixer.Sound("/2.wav")
soundC = pygame.mixer.Sound("/3.wav")

soundChannelA = pygame.mixer.Channel(1) 
soundChannelB = pygame.mixer.Channel(2)
soundChannelC = pygame.mixer.Channel(3)

print "Go . Sampler Ready."
serialFromArduino = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600)
serialFromArduino.flush()

while True:
try:
    val = ord(serialFromArduino.read())
    print(val)
    if (val == 2): 
        soundChannelA.play(soundA) 
    if (val == 3):
        soundChannelB.play(soundB)
    if (val == 4):
        soundChannelC.play(soundC)
    val = 0
    sleep(.01)
except KeyboardInterrupt: 
    exit()
```

The code was from originally a make post. Like i say it runs, recieves the arduino, but the audio is just a click. I tried with .ogg files instead and they make no difference.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Why the `sleep(.01)`?

Comment: the arudiono is sending - so its to allow time between the button press before registerinbg the next press.

Comment: ALSA LIB PCM.C:7339 is the error

Comment: You never mentioned an error before; how is this related to your problem? And the actual error message might be helpful.

Comment: i did mention an error - and i just posted the error code 15 hours ago. pygame helped me directly to solve it. its an unknown thing with audio but literally spending a few hours trying all the diff settings on init finally worked for the .wavs i had.

Comment: Can you post an answer then? I have the same problem and no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Please post the answer, as I am running into the same problem!